# Craft 2: Is there a hook for Craft Commerce Orders admin page?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

My plugin is sort of an extension for the Craft Commerce, where I need to provide custom data on the craft commerce orders page.
So I'm wondering is there a way to listen for an event, which fires when an admin navigates to the Orders page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got a solution. In my plugin's `init` function I've done the following hook:

```
craft()->templates->hook('cp.commerce.order.edit.main-pane', function (&$context) { ... }
```

If there is more 'elegant' solution, please shoot.
Cheers.